# jQuery validate with array does not work

Tags: jquery

Please consider the simple form with jQuery validation code below. Somehow I (still) go wrong with the syntax for the rules, as the validation does not work in this way (while I checked some sites on stackoverflow on this topic). How to describe the rule properly using arrays?

Please your help.

Code:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
<label class="field2" for="productname[0]"> Product name 1 </label> <input id="productname[0]" type="text" name="productname[0]"> <br>
<label class="field2" for="productname[1]"> Product name 2 </label> <input id="productname[1]" type="text" name="productname[1]"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Submit Form">
```

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

    $("#myForm").validate({

    rules: {

            'productname[]': {
                required:true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 30,
            }

            } //rules
    }); //validate()

}); //function
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems problem is in your html markup. Try to modify:

```
<label class="field2" for="productname[0]"> Product name 1 </label> <input id="productname[0]" type="text" name="productname[]"> <br />
<label class="field2" for="productname[1]"> Product name 2 </label> <input id="productname[1]" type="text" name="productname[]"> <br />
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your back-end looks like but naming the fields [0] and [1] is unnecessary

```
<label class="field2" for="productname_1"> Product name 1 </label> <input id="productname_1" type="text" name="productname[]"> <br>
<label class="field2" for="productname_2"> Product name 2 </label> <input id="productname_2" type="text" name="productname[]"> <br>
```

The above should be sufficient, and work with the validation. The server will most likely take care of converting the post query string into an Array.

Comment: thnx for your comments (!). However your code does not seem to work when I use it. It does work when changing the name values (name="productname_1", name="productname_2". In my real code I have much more product names and related fields to check, which would require writing a lot of validation rules and the reason being why I tried the arrays. The solution suggested by YD1m seems to work.